# Matching text group(s) between tags from multiline html using Python's Regex

Tags: python, html, python-re

I am trying to use python's regex to collect all text matches from multiline html code.

Here is the html code (I kept it as it is, messy):

```
<p class="SearchCard">
                    
                            Hi,

 Need AWS devops with 10+ experience

If anyone interested plz revert 
                        
                    </p>
```

If I use `regex='\"SearchCard\">(\n*\s*.*)'` I get match up to word *Hi,* included.

But if I use `regex='\"SearchCard\">(\n*\s*.*)*?<'` I get everything until end of the html file but I want to capture matched group before first '<' symbol.

Python code is bellow:

```
re.findall(regex, html)
```

I know it can be (and probably should be) done with other modules (e.g. BS4, or similar), but I am looking for solution with **re**.

Comment: Regex is not recommanded to aprse markup languages (as HTML). I'd use beautyfulsoup and XPath for that.

Comment: As mentioned prior it is very inadvisable to try to parse markup using pure regex - there are many edge cases to consider, especially when considering the potential for malformed markup. However, it may be useful for your general progression vis-a-vis understanding `re` to know that the `.` character matches all characters **except** newline (`\n`).  You can modify this behavior by passing `re.DOTALL`  when using the Python `re` module. With this argument passed to `re.findall()`, the first pattern in your question works - though `<` outside of a capturing group is needed to ignore closing tag

Comment: @JPI93 , thank you for comment. I do specifically using **regex** to have better understanding of **re**. I tried `re.DOTALL` but faced same issue.

Comment: Please html formatting as it is. I am looking for solution to capture `\s` and `\n` white matching.